# Python: Return multi-lined text as variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code

```
def output(land, oak_count, willow_count):
    l_0 = "Investigation of Trees Completed:"
    l_1 = "Land Surveyed: " + str(land)
    l_2 = "Oaks: " + str(oak_count)
    l_3 = "Willows: " + str(willow_count)

    text = []
    for i in range(0, 4):
        text.append(vars()["l_"+str(i)])

    return text

text = output("Green Forest", 5, 10)
for i in text:
    print(i)
```

gives the following output:

```
Investigation of Trees Completed:
Land Surveyed: Green Forest
Oaks: 5
Willows: 10
```

However, this seems incredibly cumbersome for large output files. It also makes it difficult to edit the output in future updates, and lines might be forgotten or need to be reordered (especially if the report contains many lines).

There is also a need to be able to return the output text to another module, so that it might be collated with other bits of information. For this reason, I stored the text as a variable.

I am looking for a way of returning the output in one go. Something along the lines of (although this doesnt work):

```
text = """
Investigation of Trees Completed:\n
Land Surveyed:""" + str(Green Forest) + """\n
Oaks: """ + str(oak_count) + """\n
Willows: """ + str(willow_count) + """\n
"""
```

and where the code also goes across multiple lines according to style guides. Unfortunately the above gives (when using `print(text)`:

```
'\nInvestigation of Trees Completed:\nLand Surveyed:Green Forest\nOaks: 5\nWillows: 10\n'
```

Note: saving text to a file by:

```
text_file = open("output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(text)
text.close
```

gives the output from above in the desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On python equal than or greater than 3.6 you can use format strings:

```
 format_string = f''' Hello this is a format string
                      the number of trees is oak = {oak_count}'''
```

({oak_count} is going to be the value of the variable oak_count.)

On older versions you can use .format():

```
 format_string = '''Hello this is a format string as well
                    the number of trees is
                    oaks = {0}
                    willows = {1}'''.format(oak_count, willow_count)
```

Both work with multiline and single line strings.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `vars()` at all (ever really), but in this case, just build the list using a list literal and return it. Also, if you're using Python 3.6 or newer, you can use f-strings for formatting, such as below:

```
def output(land, oak_count, willow_count):
    return [
        "Investigation of Trees Completed:",
        f"Land Surveyed: {land}",
        f"Oaks: {oak_count}",
        f"Willows: {willow_count}",
    ]

for line in output("Green Forest", 5, 10):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you @AKX. This is much cleaner. I can save that as a list and return it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting, like below:

```
text = f"""
Investigation of Trees Completed:\n
Land Surveyed: {str(Green Forest)} \n
Oaks: {str(oak_count)} \n
Willows: {str(willow_count)} \n
"""
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I removed the `\n` part (it was giving an extra linespace). Thank you @IoaTzimas.